# Combining Filtering and sorting in jQuery Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to find a way to combine the functionality of filtering and sorting. In other words,  I'd like to filter first by mall type, and then, within that filtered group, sort by other various ways like alphabetical, by state, by sq. ft., etc. So far, I'm not finding a way to combine these two. I can apparently filter, or sort. But not both. And in this Codepen, I can only filter, and I'm not sure why.

```js
// Switch between grid & list views
jQuery(($) => {
  $(".showSingle").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".content").hide();
    let targetSelector = $(e.currentTarget).attr("href");
    $(targetSelector).show();
  });
});
// end Switch between grid & list views

// external js: isotope.pkgd.js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
  itemSelector: ".color-shape",
  getFilterData: {
    name: '.name',
    symbol: '.status',
    size: '.size parseInt',
    category: '[data-category]',
    weight: function(itemElem) {
      var weight = $(itemElem).find('.weight').text();
      return parseFloat(weight.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));
    }
  }
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$(".filters").on("click", ".button", function(event) {
  var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $button.parents(".button-group");
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr("data-filter-group");
  // set filter for group
  filters[filterGroup] = $button.attr("data-filter");
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = concatValues(filters);
  // set filter for Isotope
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$(".button-group").each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on("click", "button", function(event) {
    $buttonGroup.find(".is-checked").removeClass("is-checked");
    var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
    $button.addClass("is-checked");
  });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues(obj) {
  var value = "";
  for (var prop in obj) {
    value += obj[prop];
  }
  return value;
}
// end Isotope Grid View

// Isotope List View
var $table = $("#div2 .table-like").isotope({
  layoutMode: "vertical",
  getSortData: {
    name: ".name",
    symbol: ".symbol",
    number: ".number parseInt",
    category: ".category",
    weight: function(itemElem) {
      var weight = $(itemElem).find(".weight").text();
      return parseFloat(weight.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ""));
    }
  }
});

// bind sort button click
$("#div2 #sorts").on("click", "button", function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr("data-sort-value");
  $table.isotope({
    sortBy: sortValue
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$("#div2 .button-group").each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on("click", "button", function() {
    $buttonGroup.find(".is-checked").removeClass("is-checked");
    $(this).addClass("is-checked");
  });
});
//end Isotope List View
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

#div1 {
  display: block;
}

#div1 .button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2));
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#div1 .button:hover {
  background-color: #8cf;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

#div1 .button:active,
#div1 .button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28f;
}

#div1 .button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

#div1 .button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}


/* ---- button-group ---- */

#div1 .button-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#div1 .button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

#div1 .button-group .button:first-child {
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

#div1 .button-group .button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}


/* ---- isotope ---- */

#div1 .grid {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


/* clear fix */

#div1 .grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ui group */

#div1 .ui-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

#div1 .ui-group h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#div1 .ui-group .button-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


/* color-shape */

#div1 .color-shape {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

#div1 .color-shape.round {
  border-radius: 35px;
}

#div1 .color-shape.big.round {
  border-radius: 75px;
}

#div1 .color-shape.red {
  background: red;
}

#div1 .color-shape.blue {
  background: blue;
}

#div1 .color-shape.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

#div1 .color-shape.wide,
.color-shape.big {
  width: 150px;
}

#div1 .color-shape.tall,
.color-shape.big {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<section id="content" class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0 5rem;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <p>You can sort our properties below by clicking on the buttons.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 d-flex">
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block ms-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle float-right" href="#div1" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle float-right" href="#div2" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="div1" class="content">

  <h1>Isotope - combination filters</h1>

  <div class="filters">

    <div class="ui-group">
      <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="type">
        <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">all</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter=".mall">malls</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter=".open">open air centers</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-group">
      <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="details">
        <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter=".state">by state</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter=".name">by name</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter=".size">by sq. ft. size</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="grid">
    <div class="color-shape small round red mall">
      <h3 class="state">WY</h3>
      <span class="name">Zaphod</span>
      <span class="size">500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="color-shape small round blue open">
      <h3 class="state">CA</h3>
      <span class="name">Ford</span>
      <span class="size">42</span>
    </div>
    <div class="color-shape small round yellow open">
      <h3 class="state">TN</h3>
      <span class="name">Dirk</span>
      <span class="size">200</span>
    </div>
    <div class="color-shape small square red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape small square blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape small square yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide round red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide round blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide round yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide square red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide square blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape wide square yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big round red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big round blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big round yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big square red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big square blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape big square yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall round red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall round blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall round yellow"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall square red"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall square blue"></div>
    <div class="color-shape tall square yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="content">

  <div id="sorts" class="button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-value="original-order">original order</button>
    <button class="button" data-sort-value="name">name</button>
    <button class="button" data-sort-value="symbol">symbol</button>
    <button class="button" data-sort-value="number">number</button>
    <button class="button" data-sort-value="weight">weight</button>
    <button class="button" data-sort-value="category">category</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="table-like">

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Mercury</div>
      <div class="symbol">Hg</div>
      <div class="number">80</div>
      <div class="weight">200.59</div>
      <div class="category">transition</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Tellurium</div>
      <div class="symbol">Te</div>
      <div class="number">52</div>
      <div class="weight">127.6</div>
      <div class="category">metalloid</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Bismuth</div>
      <div class="symbol">Bi</div>
      <div class="number">83</div>
      <div class="weight">208.980</div>
      <div class="category">post-transition</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Lead</div>
      <div class="symbol">Pb</div>
      <div class="number">82</div>
      <div class="weight">207.2</div>
      <div class="category">post-transition</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Gold</div>
      <div class="symbol">Au</div>
      <div class="number">79</div>
      <div class="weight">196.967</div>
      <div class="category">transition</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Potassium</div>
      <div class="symbol">K</div>
      <div class="number">19</div>
      <div class="weight">39.0983</div>
      <div class="category">alkali</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Sodium</div>
      <div class="symbol">Na</div>
      <div class="number">11</div>
      <div class="weight">22.99</div>
      <div class="category">alkali</div>
    </li>

    <li class="table-like__item">
      <div class="name">Cadmium</div>
      <div class="symbol">Cd</div>
      <div class="number">48</div>
      <div class="weight">112.411</div>
      <div class="category">transition</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn´t you set the filter *and* the sorting on the binded buttons? just like: `$table.isotope({
    sortBy: sortValue, filter: filterValue
  });` ? It seems to me that when filtering, you may be clearing the sorting, and vice-versa.

Comment: just read what's in the "data-" attribute for both, sorting and filtering, on both click handlers.

Comment: Can you please ask question? This is a Q&A site.

Comment: @ZacharyVance - I most definitely asked a question. That question was how to make sort and filter work together.